# Script para insertar formula con referencia de celda variable en Sheet

Tags: google-apps-script, google-hoja-de-cálculo

Necesito generar un script para que me inserte una fórmula en una celda, donde dentro de esa fórmula hay una referencia a una celda variable (`lastrow` con escritura) que esta ubicada en la misma fila de la celda de la formula en una columna especifica. Paso a detallar:

Fórmula:
`=TRANSPONER(TRANSPONER({(INDICE('Respuestas de formulario 1'!$H:$H;COINCIDIR(**A2**;'Respuestas de formulario 1'!$B:$B;0)));(INDICE('Respuestas de formulario 1'!$J:$J;COINCIDIR(**A2**;'Respuestas de formulario 1'!$B:$B;0)));(INDICE('Respuestas de formulario 1'!$L:$L;COINCIDIR(**A2**;'Respuestas de formulario 1'!$B:$B;0)))}))`

La celda A2 es la celda variable, ya que depende de cual es la ultima fila de la columna que tiene una celda escrita y no vacía.

Se me ocurrió el siguiente código:

```
function direccion(){
var ssFormula = SpreadsheetApp.openById(".........");

var source_sheet_Formula = ssFormula.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");


var origen_pn1_numNRW = source_sheet_Formula.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var origen_pn1_numNRW_2 = origen_pn1_numNRW.filter(String).length;
var destino_pn1_numNRW_33 = source_sheet_Formula.getRange("A"+origen_pn1_numNRW_2)
var numero_fila = destino_pn1_numNRW_33.getNumRows()

var celda_variable = source_sheet_Formula.getRange("Y8");

celda_variable.setValue("=DIRECCION("+numero_fila+";1)")
}
```

Pero `numero_fila` no me arroja el número correcto de la última fila escrita de la columna.

La idea final, si el código anterior resultaba, era que la fórmula original quedara de la siguiente forma en el script:

```
function insertar_formula(){
var ssFormula = SpreadsheetApp.openById(".........");

var source_sheet_Formula = ssFormula.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");

var origen_pn1_numNRW = source_sheet_Formula.getRange("A1:A").getValues();
var origen_pn1_numNRW_2 = origen_pn1_numNRW.filter(String).length;
var destino_pn1_numNRW_33 = source_sheet_Formula.getRange("A"+origen_pn1_numNRW_2)
var numero_fila = destino_pn1_numNRW_33.getNumRows()

var celda_variable.setValue("=DIRECCION("+numero_fila+";1)")


var celda_formula = source_sheet_Formula.getRange("Y8");

celda_formula.setFormula("=TRANSPONER(TRANSPONER({(INDICE('Respuestas de formulario 1'!$H:$H;COINCIDIR("**+celda_variable+**";'Respuestas de formulario 1'!$B:$B;0)));(INDICE('Respuestas de formulario 1'!$J:$J;COINCIDIR("**+celda_variable+**";'Respuestas de formulario 1'!$B:$B;0)));(INDICE('Respuestas de formulario 1'!$L:$L;COINCIDIR("**+celda_variable+**";'Respuestas de formulario 1'!$B:$B;0)))}))")
}
```

Para que coloque la formula en la celda "Y8" y dentro de la formula coloque el rango de la ultima celda escrita de la columna "A" así la puede calcular.

Espero haberme explicado y me puedan ayudar.

Answer (score 1):

Para encontrar la ultima fila existente en una hoja de calculo puedes utilizar varios métodos:

**Opcion 1:** El más simple

```
const ssFormula = SpreadsheetApp.openById(".........");
const source_sheet_Formula = ssFormula.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");
let ultimaFila = source_sheet_Formula.getLastRow()

console.log(ultimaFila)
```

Este método de arroja la **ultima fila con valor**, indistinto de la columna.

**Opcion 2:** Ultima fila de columna especifica

```
const ssFormula = SpreadsheetApp.openById(".........");
const source_sheet_Formula = ssFormula.getSheetByName("Respuestas de formulario 1");
let maximoFilas = source_sheet_Formula.getLastRow() 
let columna = 'A';
let data = source_sheet_Formula.getRange(columna+"1:"+ columna + maximoFilas).getValues(); 
for (;data[maximoFilas-1]=='' && maximoFilas>0;maximoFilas--) {}

console.log(maximoFilas)
```

Esto lee todos los datos de la columna especificado y revisa los que no están vacíos para darte el numero de la **ultima fila con valor**.

Comment: Muchas gracias. Fue de ayuda

Comment: @Emanuel Si fue lo que necesitabas, te invito a marcarla como respondida